# Calling call back function of .NET application from processors C code

Tags: .net, c

I have .NET application and C code in my board. .NET application will call C function  (To watch button has pressed or not ?) with **callback function** as argument and end its task. My C application will watch the button and when the button is pressed **callback function** (of .NET) has to be called.
How can I call that **callback function** (of .NET) from my C code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the C definition of your function the call back should be expressed as a function pointer.  For simplicity lets assume the call back returns `void` and has no arguments.

```
void NativeMethod(void (*pCallback)(void)) { 
  ...
}
```

Once this code is invoked the C code will have a simple function pointer.  It can invoke this when it pleases and it will transition into the .Net code.

On the .Net side we need to define both a delegate for the function pointer type and a PInvoke stub to use to call into the C code.

```
delegate void CallbackFunc();

[DllImport("the_native_dll")]
static extern void NativeMethod(
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] CallbackFunc cb)
```

Now the C# code can call into the native code via the `NativeMethod` function using standard delegates

Comment: That's pretty neat, I thought you'd at least need a context argument or something.